# how to share contents of dataset across all processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

As shown in the code posted below, i have contents of a dataset represented in object `mainTIFFImageDatasetContents`.
each time run() is called i collect some data in a form of an objects as shonw in the next line:

```
if (pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt > 0):
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel = GridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel()
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setRowValue(row)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setColValue(col)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setVericalStep(verticalStep)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setHorizontalStep(horizontalStep)
        =====>gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setMainTIFFImageDatasetContents(mainTIFFImageDatasetContents) #<==================
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setNDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832(NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setURLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832(URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setPixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt(pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setPixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInNoneZeroCoverageCell(_pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInNoneZeroCoverageCell)
```

when the run() return `return gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel`, i save the returned objects in a list `__iterablesOfNoneZeroCoverageCell` which will be the input iterables to another parallelized code which is indicated as shown below in
section `postTask`

the problem i am facing is related to pickling of `mainTIFFImageDatasetContents` each time an object in iterable `__iterablesOfNoneZeroCoverageCell` is passed to the run(), `mainTIFFImageDatasetContents` is picked and it is an expensive operation.
i would like to set `mainTIFFImageDatasetContents` only once in the run() ,shown in the below line, instead of setting it to each object in the iterable.:

```
for res in ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool.map(func=self.run,iterable=self.__iterables,chunksize=self.__chunkSize):
```

in other words, i would like to do something like setting a static variable so that the object is set once and no need to set it every time for each created object. i hope my point is clear

**DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool**

```
def postTask(self):
    self.__postTaskStartTime = time.time()
    
    with Pool(processes=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['proceses_count'])) as DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool.pool:
        self.__chunkSize = PoolUtils.getChunkSize(lst=self.__listOfLoopDecouplers,cpuCount=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['cpu_count']))
        logger.info(f"DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool.self.__chunkSize(task per processor):{self.__chunkSize}")
        for res in DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool.pool.map(self.run,self.__listOfLoopDecouplers,chunksize=self.__chunkSize):
            if res[0] is not None and res[1] is None and res[2] is None:
                self.__iterablesOfNoneZeroCoverageCell.append(res[0])
              
            else:
                raise Exception (f"WTF.")
    DecoupleGridCellsProfilerLoopsPool.pool.join()
    assert len(self.__iterablesOfNoneZeroCoverageCell)+len(self.__iterablesOfZeroCoverageCell)+len(self.__iterablesOfNoDataCells) == len(self.__listOfLoopDecouplers)  
    
    zeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool = ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool(self.__devModeForWSAWANTIVer2,self.__iterablesOfZeroCoverageCell)
    zeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.postTask()
    
def run(self,param:LoopDecoupler):
    row = param.getRowValue()
    col = param.getColValue()
    elevationsTIFFWindowedSegmentContents = param.getElevationsTIFFWindowedSegment()
    verticalStep = param.getVericalStep()
    horizontalStep = param.getHorizontalStep()
    mainTIFFImageDatasetContents = param.getMainTIFFImageDatasetContents()
    NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832 = param.getNDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832()
    URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832 = param.getURLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832()
    threshold = param.getThreshold()
    rowsCnt = 0
    colsCnt = 0     

    pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = 0
    pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = int(config['window']['width']) * int(config['window']['height'])
    pixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = int(config['window']['width']) * int(config['window']['height'])
    _pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInNoneZeroCoverageCell = []
    _pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell = []
    _pixelsValuesInNoDataCell = []
    
    gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel = None
    gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel = None
    gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoDataCellsModel = None
    for x in range(row,row + verticalStep):
        if rowsCnt == verticalStep:
            rowsCnt = 0
        for y in range(col,col + horizontalStep):
            if colsCnt == horizontalStep:
                colsCnt = 0
            
            pixelValue = mainTIFFImageDatasetContents[0][x][y]
            # windowIOUtils.writeContentsToFile(windowIOUtils.getPathToOutputDir()+"/"+config['window']['file_name']+".{0}".format(config['window']['file_extension']), "pixelValue:{0}\n".format(pixelValue))
            if pixelValue >= float(threshold):
                pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt+=1
                _pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInNoneZeroCoverageCell.append(elevationsTIFFWindowedSegmentContents[0][rowsCnt][colsCnt])
            elif ((pixelValue < float(threshold)) and (pixelValue > float(config['TIFF']['no_data_value']))):
                pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt-=1
                _pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell.append(elevationsTIFFWindowedSegmentContents[0][rowsCnt][colsCnt])
            elif (pixelValue <= float(config['TIFF']['no_data_value'])):
                    pixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt-=1
                    _pixelsValuesInNoDataCell.append(elevationsTIFFWindowedSegmentContents[0][rowsCnt][colsCnt])
            else:
                raise Exception ("WTF.Exception: unhandled condition for pixel value: {0}".format(pixelValue))
            # _pixelCoordinatesInWindow.append([x,y])
            colsCnt+=1
        rowsCnt+=1
    
    '''collecting data'''
    if (pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt > 0):
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel = GridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel()
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setRowValue(row)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setColValue(col)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setVericalStep(verticalStep)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setHorizontalStep(horizontalStep)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setMainTIFFImageDatasetContents(mainTIFFImageDatasetContents)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setNDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832(NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setURLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832(URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setPixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt(pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt)
        gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel.setPixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInNoneZeroCoverageCell(_pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInNoneZeroCoverageCell)

    return gridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForNoneZeroCoverageModel
```

**ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool**:

```
def postTask(self):
    self.__postTaskStartTime = time.time()
   '''initialization of variables'''
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
    with Pool(processes=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['proceses_count'])) as ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool:
        self.__chunkSize = PoolUtils.getChunkSize(lst=self.__iterables,cpuCount=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['cpu_count']))
        logger.info(f"ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.self.__chunkSize(task per processor):{self.__chunkSize}")
        for res in ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool.map(func=self.run,iterable=self.__iterables,chunksize=self.__chunkSize):
            resAllCellsForGridCellsClassifications.append(res[0])
                pass
            
    ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool.join()
    
    return 

def run(self,params:GridCellInnerLoopsIteratorsForZeroCoverageModel):
    if params is not None:
        logger.info(f"Processing zero coverage cell @(row{params.getRowValue()},col:{params.getColValue()})")
        row = params.getRowValue()
        col = params.getColValue()
        mainTIFFImageDatasetContents = params.getMainTIFFImageDatasetContents()
        NDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832 = params.getNDVIsTIFFWindowedSegmentContentsInEPSG25832()
        URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832 = params.getURLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832()
        datasetElevationsTIFFInEPSG25832 = rasterio.open(URLOrFilePathForElevationsTIFFDatasetInEPSG25832,'r')
        _pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell = params.getPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInZeroCoverageCell()
        pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = params.getPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt()
        countOfNoDataCells = params.getPixelsWithNoDataValueInTIFFImageDatasetCnt()
        outFromEPSG25832ToEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCells = []
        fourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326ForZeroCoverageCell = []
        
        output=(..,...,..,..,)
    return output
```

**code of postTask**:

```
                        def postTask(self):
    self.__postTaskStartTime = time.time()       
    
    with Pool(processes=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['proceses_count'])) as ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool:
        self.__chunkSize = PoolUtils.getChunkSize(lst=self.__iterables,cpuCount=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['cpu_count']))
        for res in ZeroCoverageCellsProcessingPool.pool.map(func=self.run,iterable=self.__iterables,chunksize=self.__chunkSize):
            resAllCellsForGridCellsClassifications.append(res[0])
            # NDVIs
```

Comment: I know that variables name should be descriptive but there ought to be some limit to that :)

Answer (score 1):

this example shows how to copy a variable once to all children using an initializer that only runs once per child process.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def foo(number):
    print(number, global_obj)

def initializer_func(argument):
    global global_obj
    global_obj = argument

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parent_obj = "hello"
    with Pool(processes=1, initializer=initializer_func,initargs=(parent_obj,)) as pool:
        pool.map(foo, range(4))
```

```
0 hello
1 hello
2 hello
3 hello
```

PS: for a new programmers you might want your names to be descriptive to help everyone understand the code, but very long names is a clear sign of coupling, and makes it harder to avoid breaking [PEP 8 line length stadard](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) so you end up with code that is difficult to read and maintain and even harder to extend, for example no one (me included) bothered to read your code, and forcing the future maintainer to do so will be a crime, the only exception to that is if you get paid by the number of letters in your code.